# Will array return by reference in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, pass-by-reference

I [found](https://java.net/projects/jai-core/sources/svn/content/trunk/src/share/classes/javax/media/jai/PerspectiveTransform.java?rev=111) the following code in `transform` method of class [`PerspectiveTransform`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/java-media/jai/forDevelopers/jai-apidocs/javax/media/jai/PerspectiveTransform.html) in `JAI` library:

```
public void transform(double[] srcPts, int srcOff,
              double[] dstPts, int dstOff,
              int numPts) {

        if ( srcPts == null ) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(JaiI18N.getString("Generic0"));
        }

        if (dstPts == null) {
            dstPts = new double[numPts * 2 + dstOff];
        }

        while (numPts-- > 0) {
            double x = srcPts[srcOff++];
            double y = srcPts[srcOff++];
            double w = m20 * x + m21 * y + m22;

            if (w == 0) {
                dstPts[dstOff++] = x;
                dstPts[dstOff++] = y;
            } else {
                dstPts[dstOff++] = (m00 * x + m01 * y + m02) / w;
                dstPts[dstOff++] = (m10 * x + m11 * y + m12) / w;
            }
        }
    }
```

Looks like if `dstPts` is `null`, then new array is created. But this array won't return outside, isn't it?

Comment: Yep, you are right, java pass by value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, if that is the actual code. I imagine people aren't passing nulls as parameters when they're using the method, but even so that's a bug.

Answer (score 3):

Just a note: Java is always pass by value. The little line at the bottom is that when you pass an object as a parameter, its reference is the value that is actually passed.

For example, C# has the `ref` keyword, which allows the passing of a reference. In Java, you have to wrap your object in a sort of container and work with the container, so you can switch the underlying element freely.

As you say, the new array won't be accessible from the outside unless it is returned. I understand that was done to prevent the following `while` from throwing a NPE, but the processing result is lost as the method is actually coded.

Comment: **Java is always pass by value**. Exactly. No ifs or buts.

Comment: "is that when you pass an object as a parameter" The thing is, you cannot "pass an object as a parameter" in Java. Objects are not values in Java. The only types in Java are primitive types and reference types. Therefore, each parameter must be of a primitive type or reference type. There is no "object type".

Comment: @newacct "The little line at the bottom is that when you pass an object as a parameter, **its reference is the value that is actually passed**." I don't know if you were clarifying or correcting me, but your quote seems out of context.

Comment: @Gamb: The fact that you are saying "pass an object" is itself wrong because you cannot pass something that is not a value.

Comment: @newacct Again, you're missing the context. The line serves as a clarification, not an affirmation.

Comment: @Gamb: You're propagating a misconception that there are "objects" in the code. Nothing in the code is an "object". `dstPts` is not an "object". `srcPts` is not an "object".

Comment: @newacct "When you do X, you're actually doing Y". I don't see what misconception I'm propagating, specially after the "Java is always pass by value" part.

Comment: @Gamb: But why would anyone think you're "doing X"? Why would anyone think that there is a line where you're "passing an object", when nowhere in the code do you see objects?

Comment: @newacct You're trying to support a subjective argument over a technicality. By stripping the whole concept of Object from the interpretation of a code, you're just hurting the whole paradigm and the way to grasp it. **"Passing an object" is a very used figurative quote to address this reference handling**. Anyone with a minimum understanding of the paradigm knows how to separate the concept of Object from its technical implementation. I urge you to roam SO and correct all the posts that use this methaphor too. I warn you, tough, that everybody understands what's happening under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are Objects, and their reference is passed by value.

Comment: You gave a right answer but put the most important part last.

Comment: Yes. But it's a copy of the _original_ reference.  So you can't do `dstPts = new double[numPts * 2 + dstOff];` in a method and expect it to have any effect outside.   So you're giving a mostly correct but misleading answer.

Comment: Objects cannot be passed, period.